# how to make skipNullOn dynamic in dataweave script?

Tags: mule, dataweave

Based on Boolean variable I want to get output. If variable is true null parameters should not visible in output and if false null parameters should be visible. How to make skipNullOn dynamic in mule dataweave script?

Answer (score 0):

@swamy Thota not sure if you can do it in dataweave. 
Alternate option i can think off is, use choice and 2 dataweaves, one will skip null and other will allow null.

Comment: Thank you @Suyog Sathe. Just looking for to do it in dataweave. Choice is final option if it didn't worked in dataweave.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a flow variable , the use a choice and create two different mapping one for true condition and one for false.
 It will be something as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:encryption="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/encryption" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 

 <flow name="file2fileFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\Tushar\Training\DataWeave\in" moveToDirectory="D:\Tushar\Training\DataWeave\out" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <set-variable variableName="test" value="#['a']" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <choice tracking:enable-default-events="true" doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars.test] == 'a'">
                <dw:transform-message doc:name="If Value True">
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
}]]></dw:set-payload>
                </dw:transform-message>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <dw:transform-message doc:name="If Value false">
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
}]]></dw:set-payload>
                </dw:transform-message>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <logger  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint  outputPattern="output.txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Thank you @Tushar. Just looking for to do it in dataweave. Choice is final option if it didn't worked in dataweave.

Answer (score 0):

You can load dw script from file and dynamic replace in text script skipNullOn value. Then, call the MEL function `#[dw(<script>, [<output type>] ]`

More examles you can see there: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/ka4340000004GbvAAE/Dynamic-DataWeave-Script